# Facebook Feed, post two pictures in wall. Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hello im trying to post two pictures to my wall with javascript sdk.

I want to do something like this:
[image: Example]

I know how to post to my wall, using: " FB.api('/me/feed', 'post " method, but this allow me only to upload one picture. How can i upload two ?

Thanks

Comment: That can’t be done via API at the moment – you can only make to separate uploads.

Comment: Ok, i was afraid of that. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the photos and post them.

I guess Facebook will automatically group them together if they belong to the same album.

```
for(var i=0; i<picture.length; i++){
    ....
    params['picture'] = picture1;
    ....
    FB.api( ... );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i dont get it. Im doing this to post to wall: 
var params = {};     
params['message'] = 'My message';
params['name'] = 'My Name';
params['picture'] = 'HERE I PUT THE URL FOR THE PICTURE';
  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params);

Comment: I'm just saying that loop though the pictures link and call apis in loop

Comment: No, this doesnt work, cause when i do what you suggested, it post 2 different posts, not one with two pictures.